# add transaction manually to Google Analytics and eCommerce

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, tracking

I'm using the following tutorial, http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2014/03/04/tracking-offline-transactions-universal-analytics/ which tells us how to add a transaction manually using a url like the following:

http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-123456789-1&cid=75839030.509493873&t=transaction&ti=52ea5aab1f0c2&tr=1100&cd1=52ea5a8bc6a4a

This works ok. However, the eCommerce part of GA does not register a conversion, so it's not possible to use the multi channel funnels report.

I'm wondering is there a way to register a sale similar to how a shopping cart would on a webpage? Would I have to add in the "clientId" for the customer, into the cart so the sale can be recorded against all the other actions in GA?

OR am I doing something wrong? Such as not registering an item? Would this trigger the ecommerce conversion to register?

Either way, somehow the ecommerce tag is not firing, so I can't record multi channel funnels based on clientId

Answer (score 0):

You need save clientId in custom dimensions and in your site (it can be hide field, for example)
If you send transaction with use real clientid (send cid and cd# parameters) = this transaction will be linked with this user and all actions with this cid
On my practice better send t=event&ec=ecommerce&ea=purchase&pa=purchse&item...
With this method I have all data in ecommerce reports